# How to storage date interval into MySQL by laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know that:

```
Schema::create('xxx', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamp('expired_at');
});
```

And I get a MySQL table with a column(`expired_at`) which storage a time point.

But now I want to storage a time interval(such as, `117 seconds` or `3 hours and 43 minutes` and so on) into MySQL by laravel migration.

Any suggestion about that task?

Comment: You can use timestamp, when you inserting data get interval and after that add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mention you want to store `117 seconds` or `3 hours and 43 minutes`, means you need a column with datatype varchar. So add a new column in table using migration like:

```
$table->string('column_name');
```

and then run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

or

You can put migrations in more folders and run something like:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/app/database/migrations/my_migrations
```

Comment: But how to transform these strings into date interval which I can calculate date?

Comment: You can do this in php using `date()` and `time()` functions